# Problem to connect Python Kafka producer from within docker compose

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to produce to kafka topic from a Python project and keep getting this errors -

```
%3|1704912351.479|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka:9092/bootstrap]: kafka:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#172.25.0.2:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1704912356.486|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1001]: localhost:9092/1001: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1704912356.671|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1001]: localhost:9092/1001: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1704912391.678|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1001]: localhost:9092/1001: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 1ms in state CONNECT, 6 identical error(s) suppressed)
%3|1704912430.361|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:localhost:9092/1001]: localhost:9092/1001: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 1ms in state CONNECT, 4 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

This is the code of the producer -

```
def receipt(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print('Error: {}'.format(err))
    else:
        message = 'Produced message on topic {} with value of {}\n'.format(msg.topic(), msg.value().decode('utf-8'))
        logging.info(message)
        print(message)

producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092'})
producer.produce('payment_kafka', value="hello".encode('utf-8'), callback=receipt)
producer.poll(1)
producer.flush()
```

and this is the docker compose yaml -

```
version: '3'

services:
  flask-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test-topic:1:1"
    hostname: kafka

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    expose:
      - "2181"
```

and the docker file -

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
EXPOSE 5000

ENV FLASK_APP=main.py

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?